# Why $x^p - \alpha^p = (x - \alpha)^p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

[image]

I want to ask a question. Why $x^p - \alpha^p = (x - \alpha)^p$?

Comment: Hint: Use the binomial formula to compute $(x-\alpha)^p$ and show that most binomial coeffiecients vanish.

Comment: Expanding **red_trumpet**'s comment, check that $\binom{p}{k}\equiv0\ (\text{mod }p)$ for $0<k<p$. Then applying the binomial theorem, $$(x-\alpha)^p=x^p+(-\alpha)^p$$ since all the intermediate terms vanish by the previous observation. Then, for $p$ odd, this already gives the desired equality, and for $p=2$ we can utilize $\alpha^2=-\alpha^2$.